# FlexboxLayout addChild is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to mount a visualization for data downloaded by REST API but gives error on dynamic making by typescript.
The data is coming correctly from the server.

```
<FlexboxLayout
    flexWrap="wrap"
    #flex
>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

On typescript:

```
import { FlexboxLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/flexbox-layout/flexbox-layout';
import { StackLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout';
import { Image } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/image';
import { Label } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/label';

// ...

@ViewChild('flex',{static: false}) flex: FlexboxLayout;

ngOnInit() {
  // Populate the categories variable with server data

  categories.forEach((cat) => {
    this.createCategView(cat);
  });
}

createCategView(c: Category) {
  let stack = new StackLayout();
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = c.image;
  img.stretch = "none";
  img.width = 25;
  img.height = 25;

  let label = new Label();
  label.text = c.name;

  stack.addChild(img);
  stack.addChild(label);

  this.flex.addChild( stack );
}
```

But this last command line returns an error saying that ***this.flex.addChild*** method is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you may only be able to assign Angular Component as type to variable annotated with ViewChild. So you can not read  `flex` as FlexboxLayout but **ElementRef**.

```
@ViewChild('flex',{static: false}) flex: ElementRef;
```

Also `ngOnInit` may be little too early, try `ngAfterViewInit` or `loaded` event of the layout itself.

Comment: Hey @Manoj thank you! I did what you recommended, called the ngAfterViewInit method and changed FlexboxLayout for ElementRef. Because to add inside the FlexBox just do the following: let component: ==> FlexboxLayout = this.flex.nativeElement; component.addChild (stack);

Comment: let component: FlexboxLayout = this.flex.nativeElement;

Comment: component.addChild (stack);